# Node.js React: Can't add property context, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am currently trying to implement an isomorphic react component in my node.js + express build. However, when I try to include the said component into my jade template to render it, I get this error: **TypeError: Can't add property context, object is not extensible**

Here is my routes file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var React = require('react/addons'),
  ReactApp = React.createFactory(require('../../react/components/ReactApp'));

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var reactAppEl = ReactApp();
  console.log(reactAppEl);
  var reactHtml = React.renderToString(reactAppEl);
  res.render('index', { reactOutput: reactHtml });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The component:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react/addons');

/* create factory with griddle component */
var Griddle = React.createFactory(require('griddle-react'));

var fakeData = require('../data/fakeData.js').fakeData;
var columnMeta = require('../data/columnMeta.js').columnMeta;
var resultsPerPage = 200;

var ReactApp = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function () {
    console.log(fakeData);

  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id="table-area">

        <Griddle results={fakeData}
                 columnMetadata={columnMeta}
                 resultsPerPage={resultsPerPage}
                 tableClassName="table"/>

      </div>
    )
  }
});

/* Module.exports instead of normal dom mounting */
module.exports = ReactApp;
```

Also my gulp task throws a warning saying **Warning: Component(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render` in your component or you may have accidentally tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.
Warning: Don't set the props property of the React element. Instead, specify the correct value when initially creating the element.**

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding a `react.createFactory()` call around `griddle-react`, you signify that you are going to use plain JavaScript instead of JSX. Thus, you need to use a JavaScript function for Griddle in the subsequent render function:

```
return Griddle({results: fakeData,
                columnMetadata: columnMeta,
                resultsPerPage: resultsPerPage,
                tableClassName: "table"});
```

If you would like to use the JSX syntax that you already have, simply require `griddle-react` without the `React.createFactory()` call.